# Differential of a Map

Tags: differential-geometry

I have the following map that embeds the Torus $T^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$$f(\theta, \phi)=(cos\theta(R+rcos(\phi)),sin\theta(R+rcos(\phi)), rsin\phi)$$

noting that $0<r<R$.

I want to compute the differential of $f$, $f_*$, that maps $T_P(T^2)$ to $T_{f(p)}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

This topic is extremely confusing to me.  I am not sure how to really approach the problem at all.  I believe that if $v\in T_p(T^2)$, then I choose a smooth curve $g:\mathbb{R}\to T^2$ s.t. $g(0)=p$ and $g'(0)=v$, then $df(p)v=\frac{d}{dt}f(g(t))$ at $t=0$.

I don't really know what to do with all this.  I don't know where to go.  If someone has a good example or a good source to look at that would help explain this problem, or if someone could help me with this problem that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DavidHolden definitely it's changed already thanks!

Comment: I suggest going through John M. Lee's excellent book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (2nd Edition). Chapter 3 Tangent Vectors gives you a concrete description on how to go about such problems (http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9982-5)

Answer (score 3):

The differential of the map is given by the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). Basically what you want to do is take all of the partial derivatives of the coordinate functions and assemble them into a matrix. As you said this matrix should be a transformation from $T_p(T^2) \to T_{f(p)}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ so we want a $3 \times 2$ matrix. The matrix will look like: $  \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} \end{bmatrix} $. For example $\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} = -sinθ(R+rcos(ϕ))  $ If you'd like to know the differential at a particular point on the torus, just plug in the $(\theta, \phi)$ coordinates.

Comment: I am very confused, something here has to be wrong. The differential map maps tangent spaces to tangent spaces. Since both he torus and the torus embedded in R^3 are 2D manifolds, the differential map should be a map from a 2D space to a 2D space, so a 2x@ matrix, why is it a 3x2?